# Angular 2 - Code is not correctly executed in callback (3rd party lib)

Tags: typescript, angular, stripe-payments

I've got the following problem with my Angular 2 application (version: 2.0.0-rc.1).

We are using Stripe to enable users to pay with credit cards. We have a `createToken` function, which is calling the Stripe API to generate a token, which is then send to our API. The problem occurs in the callback of the stripe function.

Basically after a valid token has been returned. The app just should show a notificaton and navigate to the home-route. But somehow the app is stuck. The `checkoutComponent` get's destroyed in the Dom. The router navigates correctly to the home-route. But it is never rendered, also the notifications (which is basically independent from the `homeComponent` is also not showing up).

Here is the `createToken` function:

```
createToken(formData) {
    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        'number': formData.ccnumber,
        'exp_month': formData.exp_month,
        'exp_year': formData.exp_year,
        'cvc': formData.cvc
    }, (status, response) => {
        console.log('stripe callback', this, status, response);
        if (status.toString().charAt(0) == '4') {
            this._notes.add(new Notification('warning', this.translate.instant('notifications.checkout.stripeError')));
        } else {
            this._notes.add(new Notification('success', this.translate.instant('notifications.checkout.success')));
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure, because I never encountered a similar problem yet. Maybe it is related to Stripe somehow, because using the navigate-method of the router works on other places. Maybe there is a problem with the execution within the callback of a 3rd-party lib?

Every hint is appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to inject `ApplicationRef` in the `contructor` where the `createToken` function resides. And after you navigate in the callback call the function `applicationRef.tick()`

Comment: @PierreDuc at least the notification is showing up now. But the homeComponent still doesnt get rendered. although the router navigtes correctly to /

Comment: navigate returns a `promise`, try adding the `applicationRef.tick()` to then `then()` of navigate like: `this.router.navigate(['/']).then(() => {this.applicationRef.tick()});`

Comment: @PierreDuc thank you very much! using the then()-function in combiniation with the appRef.tick() does the trick :)

Comment: Created an answer for you. Glad i could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's formulate an answer then :)

The third party library you are using probably works outside the `zone` changedetection. There are several methods to resolve this, one of them is triggering a changedetection cycle using `ApplicationRef`.

Inject the `ApplicationRef` in the contructor like:

```
constructor(private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef){}
```

Then after the navigation is finished perform a `tick()`

```
this.router.navigate(['/']).then(() => {
    this._applicationRef.tick();
});
```